# Plotting cva.glmnet()

Tags: r, plot, glmnet

I have a plot from a `cva.glmnet()` object.

The plot's legend is in the way, and I can't figure out how to move it to the right and give it a legend title.

Here's some sample code that gives a similar issue.

```
set.seed(100)
a <- runif(1000) %>% round()
b <- runif(1000) %>% round()
c <- runif(1000) %>% round()
d <- runif(1000) %>% round()
datatest <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))
cvtest <- cva.glmnet(d ~ a+b+c, data= datatest, family = "binomial")
plot(cvtest)
```

Here's a picture of the output:

[image]

I've tried adding a legend and using `ggplot()`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. We can still set legend coordinates to `NULL` and customize a `legend`.

```
par(mar=c(4, 4, 1, 1)+.1)
glmnetUtils:::plot.cva.glmnet(cvtest, legend.x=NULL, legend.y=NULL)  ## just plot(.) is sufficient
a <- cvtest$alpha
legend('topright', leg=a, lty=1, col=topo.colors(length(a)), ncol=2, cex=.8)
```

[image]

Note, that there's no `ggplot2` package involved which is why your attempt didn't work.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that. I did not know of the plot.cva.glmnet() function.

Comment: @anon1234 It's actually the method dispatched when calling `plot()` on an `"cva.glmnet"` object, `plot(cvtest, legend.x=NULL, legend.y=NULL)` is sufficient.